# What is the default orientation of the camera in OpenCV projectPoints()?

Tags: python, opencv

Exactly what the title says. If I pass [0,0,0] into `cv2.projectPoints()` as rvec, whats the orientation? What direction is it facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rotation vector's length encodes the amount of rotation in radians.

A vector of length `0` encodes a rotation of **nothing at all**.

Such a "rotation" has no unique axis. It's an identity transformation.

the `rvec` argument to `cv::projectPoints()` *does not* represent a camera angle/orientation. It represents the orientation of the model points, at the model's position. The `tvec` positions the model's points in front of the camera.

If your points are already relative to the camera's coordinate frame, then you must use zero rotation and zero translation.

Comment: My 3d points are relative to the camera's center of projection. Meaning the center of projection is at the origin. How would `projectPoints()` know which 2d points the 3d points are projected onto if it doesn't know the cameras orientation? Which axis is it pointing along?

Comment: OpenCV's coordinate system is right-handed and X right, Y down (screen), Z far.